# How to install a second version of chromium in raspbian

Tags: raspbian, chromium, streaming

I followed [this guide to watch WidevineCDM pages](https://thepi.io/how-to-watch-netflix-on-the-raspberry-pi/) (like netflix, amazon video, ...) on raspbian, which basically downgraded the pre-installed chromium.

It works fine and I can watch those streaming sites. But I noticed that youtube isn't as smooth as in the newer version, where I could watch 720p after a short buffering very well (didn't try 1080p). Now with the older version I can only watch 480p content smoothly.

As you can see it's meant as a streaming device on my tv and I am new to this.

How can I install a second (newer/newest) version of chromium for watching youtube?